# What are the essential .htaccess error pages to create?

Tags: html, .htaccess, error-handling

I know that a 404 page is essential, however what are the other most common errors that developers should create error pages for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list with client errors and server error.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

I would create a page for these specific error codes because the are common:

```
400 Bad Request
401 Unauthorized
403 Forbidden
404 Not Found
500 Internal Server Error
503 Service Unavailable
```

And then have an ErrorDocument directive for all the rest of the error code that lead to the same page maybe. This is in case you want to have a custom error page for all error codes.